# Analyze a dump file that contains a MSVCR exception

Tags: debugging, winapi, windbg

I have the following thread stack with a msvcr100!_CxxThrowException.

```
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0973ef38 7739bf53 7739610a 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
01 0973ef70 7738965e 0019029e 00000000 00000001 user32!NtUserWaitMessage+0xc
02 0973ef98 7739f762 77380000 0016aa20 00000000 user32!InternalDialogBox+0xd0
03 0973f258 7739f047 0973f3b4 00000000 ffffffff user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x94b
04 0973f3a8 7739eec9 0973f3b4 00000028 00000000 user32!MessageBoxWorker+0x2ba
05 0973f400 773d7d0d 00000000 001aaf18 0019bb60 user32!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0x7a
06 0973f434 773c42c8 00000000 7787b9f0 7786c24c user32!MessageBoxTimeoutA+0x9c
07 0973f454 773c42a4 00000000 7787b9f0 7786c24c user32!MessageBoxExA+0x1b
08 0973f470 7786f265 00000000 7787b9f0 7786c24c user32!MessageBoxA+0x45
09 0973f4a4 7786c20f 7787b9f0 7786c24c 00012010 netman!__crtMessageBoxA+0xf6
0a 0973f4cc 7786f34e 0000000a 00000000 0973f788 netman!_NMSG_WRITE+0x127
0b 0973f4fc 7786d6b6 77ecb7c0 0973f760 77e761b7 netman!abort+0x7
0c 0973f508 77e761b7 0973f788 00000000 00000000 netman!__CxxUnhandledExceptionFilter+0x2f
0d 0973f760 77e792a3 0973f788 77e61ac1 0973f790 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x12a
0e 0973f768 77e61ac1 0973f790 00000000 0973f790 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x4a
0f 0973f790 7c828772 0973fb4c 0973ffdc 0973f86c kernel32!_except_handler3+0x61
10 0973f7b4 7c828743 0973fb4c 0973ffdc 0973f86c ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
11 0973f85c 7c82865c 09737000 0973f86c 00010007 ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
12 0973fb3c 77e4bef7 0973fb4c 0000000f e06d7363 ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0x3d
13 0973fb9c 78ac872d e06d7363 00000001 00000003 kernel32!RaiseException+0x53
14 0973fbd4 0084bb9e 0973fc38 00bd8470 9adbd99a msvcr100!_CxxThrowException+0x48
```

When I look a the msvcr100!_CxxThrowException frame I see the following information. How can I progressive analyze this dump to determine the cause of the MSVCR exception?

```
14 0973fbd4 0084bb9e msvcr100!_CxxThrowException+0x48 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\throw.cpp @ 157]
0973fbdc          void * pExceptionObject = 0x0973fc38
0973fbe0          struct _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo = 0x00bd8470
0973fbb4          struct EHExceptionRecord ThisException = struct EHExceptionRecord
78ac8734          struct EHExceptionRecord ExceptionTemplate = struct EHExceptionRecord
```

Comment: Is this really the end of the call stack? Nothing below the last line?

Comment: no the other frames have private symbols so I did not provide.

Comment: But then it should be clear what is the next step: Check the location(s) shown to you in the next line(s) and think about what could have caused those lines in your code to fail.

Comment: I dont have the symbols to the code. So I wanted to look at what exception msvcr is throwing.

Comment: Ah I see. If I read this trace correctly, the parameters of the Win32 exception should be located at the pointer at `0973fb3c+14`. Try `dpp poi(0973fb3c+14) l3`, you should see the exception type in the 2nd line (let's hope it's not a totally custom exception where you don't have the symbols to get its class)

Comment: Can you enlighten me regarding the decision to use this 0973fb3c+14 address?

Comment: First, I think it should be `0973fb9c` and not `0973fb3c`, sorry. How it works: I'm trying to get the arguments to `RaiseException`. Enter `dds 0973fb9c la` to see what I mean. 1st line is stored EBP, 2nd line is return address to `_CxxThrowException`, 3rd-6th line are the arguments. The 4th argument is `lpArguments` (see [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552(v=vs.85).aspx)) and is a pointer to an array of exception arguments (which I get here using `+8+(4-1)*4` following my previous logic), one of those being the exception type.

Comment: If it's a known exception type (where you have symbols), you could use `dt` to view members of the exception class.

Comment: awesome! and it looks to be a custom exception type however, using dc I get a file not found no access printout. I also notice that I could get the same conclusion by dd void * pExceptionObject = 0x0973fc38. Then dc first value of the memory. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111032/discussion-between-d-blk-and-cherrydt).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** At the time I wrote this answer, I wasn't aware of the better, less complicated approaches suggested by the other posters below. So please scroll down and check their answers out as well!

---

According to your comments, you can't really analyze the stack trace further than this point.

To at least get details about the exception itself (only if it's a exception you have symbols for, such as one in `std`), you can do the following:

I prepared a simple test file:

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Oh noez!");
}
```

Then I ran it in WinDbg:

```
CommandLine: Z:\Temp\testexception\bin\Debug\testexception.exe

************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\users\david\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\users\david\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00910000 00919000   testexception.exe
ModLoad: 771a0000 7731b000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 75b60000 75c40000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 73ef0000 7406e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 0fb60000 0fcd3000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSVCR100D.dll
(4de4.178c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000003 ecx=039b0000 edx=00000000 esi=009100e8 edi=00360000
eip=7724ccbc esp=0018f524 ebp=0018f550 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
7724ccbc cc              int     3
Processing initial command '.prefer_dml 1'
0:000> .prefer_dml 1
DML versions of commands on by default
0:000> bp ntdll!ExecuteHandler2 <<<<<< This is just to get a stack more similar to yours
0:000> g
(4de4.178c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=64905de5 edx=7722b670 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=7722b62c esp=0018f3cc ebp=0018f490 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ExecuteHandler2:
7722b62c 55              push    ebp
0:000> kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0018f3c8 7722b624 0018f4a8 0018fa4c 0018f4f8 ntdll!ExecuteHandler2
01 0018f490 77218e7f 0018f4a8 0018f4f8 0018f4a8 ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
02 0018f490 73fadad8 0018f4a8 0018f4f8 0018f4a8 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
03<0018f9b0>0fc5cf82 e06d7363 00000001 00000003 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x48
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for testexception.exe
04 0018f9f0 00911071 0018fa00 009153a8 00914790 MSVCR100D!_CxxThrowException+0x52
05 0018fa0c 009114df 00000001 00a14f78 00a12358 testexception!main+0x21
06 0018fa5c 0091130f 0018fa78 75b738f4 00360000 testexception!__tmainCRTStartup+0x1bf
07 0018fa64 75b738f4 00360000 75b738d0 380b229d testexception!mainCRTStartup+0xf
08 0018fa78 77205de3 00360000 6488a725 00000000 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
09 0018fac0 77205dae ffffffff 7722b7d2 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
0a 0018fad0 00000000 00911300 00360000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000> dds 0018f9b0 l6 <<<<<< The address is from the line with RaiseException above, I marked it with < >
0018f9b0  0018f9f0
0018f9b4  0fc5cf82 MSVCR100D!_CxxThrowException+0x52
0018f9b8  e06d7363
0018f9bc  00000001
0018f9c0  00000003
0018f9c4  0018f9e4 <<<<<< This is the address of the arguments array
0:000> dpp 0018f9e4 l3
0018f9e4  19930520
0018f9e8 <0018fa00>00914790 <testexception!std::runtime_error>::`vftable' <<<<<< this is the exception
0018f9ec  009153a8 00000000
0:000> dt 0018fa00 testexception!std::runtime_error <<<<<< remove the `vftable` part (again marked with < > above)
   +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x00914790 
   +0x004 _Mywhat          : 0x00a11068  "Oh noez!" <<<<<< Here is our message from the code
   +0x008 _Mydofree        : 1
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to assist with this. I turns out to be a custom exception.

Comment: Is it possible to extract exception raise address from exception record? I mean not the address for RaiseException, but address of code which have called _CxxThrowException.

Answer (score 5):

@CherryDT's answer is probably fine. I just want to share an alternative approach.

1. `.symfix`
2. `.sympath+ <your private symbols>`
3. `.reload`
4. `.exr -1`
5. `dp <parameter 1> L1`
6. `ln <result of dp>`
7. `dt <type of ln> <parameter 1>`

It should look something like this (skipping the symbols parts):

```
0:000> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 7689c41f (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000058)
   ExceptionCode: e06d7363 (C++ EH exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 19930520
   Parameter[1]: 004bfb68
   Parameter[2]: 003370b8

0:000> dp 004bfb68 L1
004bfb68  0f5cf1d0

0:000> ln 0f5cf1d0
(0f5cf1d0)   MSVCR110D!std::exception::`vftable'   |  (0f5cf1d8)   MSVCR110D!`string'
Exact matches:
    MSVCR110D!std::exception::`vftable' = <no type information>

0:000> dt std::exception 004bfb68
SimpleCppCrash!std::exception
   +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x0f5cf1d0 
   +0x004 _Mywhat          : 0x0059f410  "Ouch: This application crashed because ..."
   +0x008 _Mydofree        : 1
```

If you have trouble with the symbols for MSVCRxxD, I found that a `!analyze -v` helps (I did not find out what that actually does to fix the problem).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is much more elegant than mine!

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate Approach**

`$exr_param0,14 are PseudoRegisters for` **_EXCEPTION_RECORD->ExceptionInformation[15]**

ExceptionInformation[2]  is pExceptionObject

```
0:000> da poi($exr_param1+4)
0046ad00  "Oh noez!"
```

if you use the latest windbg drop you can use the Natvis Expression Evaluator
to view it like this

```
0:000> dx Debugger.State.DebuggerVariables.curprocess.Threads.First().Stack.Frames[1].LocalVariables.ThisException.params
Debugger.State.DebuggerVariables.curprocess.Threads.First().Stack.Frames[1].LocalVariables.ThisException.params                 [Type: EHExceptionRecord::EHParameters]
    [+0x000] magicNumber      : 0x19930520
    [+0x004] pExceptionObject : 0x30f9a4 [Type: void *]
    [+0x008] pThrowInfo       : 0x133728 [Type: _s_ThrowInfo *]
```

or

```
0:000> ?? ((stdexcept!std::runtime_error *) @$exr_param1 )->_Data
struct __std_exception_data
   +0x000 _What            : 0x003dad00  "Oh noez!"
   +0x004 _DoFree          : 1
```